# Mouse stops working on Windows , fixed only by new account creation

Tags: windows, mouse

I have had this issue for ages and now I am sick and tired on it.
The issue is with Dell Inspirion 1564 laptop with touchpad and Windows 7 Ultimate on it.
Now and then mouse just stops working without any traces of issue in Eventviewer.
The only solution I found is to create new account.Naturally it is a pain as I have to migrate  settings and data every time.
Does anyone has any idea where to start to fix this?
Thank you !

Comment: Are you talking about the trackpad or an external mouse?

Comment: Are you using the latest chipset and input drivers?  When you look at the "Device Manager", are there any flagged devices?